# Fill negative space of a CA Layer

Tags: swift, xcode, cashapelayer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZooS.jpg)I created a rounded rectangle mask to overlay a UIImageView I have on the top of the screen, however I want the outer space to be filled and not the actual rounded rectangle.

```
        let topMaskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

         topMaskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 45, width: 375, height: 712), cornerRadius: 20.0).cgPath

        topMaskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        topMaskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
        cameraTopImage.layer.insertSublayer(topMaskLayer, at: 2)
```

I want to fill in the area above the green (concave rectangle). And the green image is cut off right now because of the UIImageView(that's fine)

Comment: Composite two paths , one your rounded rect , one a rect described by bounds of the layer. `UIBezierPath.append` should do the trick. Ordering matters (I think) , do the bounds first.

Comment: I ended up building out the custom shape using addCurveTo